# Why does flex-grow not work next to wrapped sibling?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a parent div with two child divs. The 2nd child is set to flex-grow. This works great, unless text has wrapped within the first column. In this case, it leaves a big empty space. Why is that, and can it be fixed?

This is the result I would Expect:
[image]

This is what is actually happening:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 225px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 3px;
}

.parent > div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    pading: 3px;
    padding: 2px;
  }

.child2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
  Short
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
  +
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
  Long NamedItem Thingamagig AnotherBigLong WordHere1234
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
  +
  </div>
</div>

<br>

Why is this space here ↑
```

Comment: What result do you want ?
.child1 taking just his space and .child2 taking the remaining ?

Comment: I want the second child to take up the remaining space

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a long string.
Add `word-break: break-all` to `.parent > div` and you'll understand what is happening.

You'll want to tweak `.child1` with :

```
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: 0;
```

or maybe

```
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: 80%;
```

(I put this syntax because it works better with IE)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My apologies if I didn't explain the expected result very well. I've updated my question. 

I understand it's due a long string, but normally when text wraps the parent element is not expanded as if `break-all` was being applied.

The answer you suggested unfortunately breaks the layout of the first instance in my example.